# Django Unit test

Tags: django, django-apps, django-unittest

i have two servers,one working as api and another used to retrieve the data from api(webui).If i perform any unit tests for views in webui,it is creating objects in api.How to delete the objects in api after the testing is complete?Can you suggest any ways to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing then you should have a separate system that does not impact upon anything that is being used in production.

You could use mocks to create the intended responses from the api for example.